# Is there a workaround to get the public Leaderboard with getLeaderboardIntent()?

Tags: android, public, google-play-games

Opening the Google Games activity containing a specific leaderboard is quite easy: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getLeaderboardIntent(java.lang.String)

But I fond this a pity that the Public scores are not opened.
Most of my users have in fact not a lot of friends on G+, so the page looks empty, and most of my users have ,o motivations as they are most likely at the first place.

That's why I would like to open the public results (second tab)

[image]

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating your own view of the google leaderboard. I mean by that, loading each public score individually and creating your own leaderboard table in your app.

Unfortunately what you are looking for is some configuration in the google getLeaderboardIntent() method that would alow to load directly the correct page with google leaderboard interface. This should have work and google created different method with getLeaderboardIntent() depending on input types and numbers. However it never worked for me.

I explained it a little bit by anwsering this post :
[How to open "All" by default instead of "Social" in Google Leaderboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415206/how-to-open-all-by-default-instead-of-social-in-google-leaderboard/37754950#37754950)