# How to open "All" by default instead of "Social" in Google Leaderboard?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, google-play-developer-api

I have integrated Google Leaderboard in my android game app. When I open it, it goes to "Social" mode by default (aka my Google circle). I need to manually switch to "All" mode (players from all around the world). How can I make "All" mode default?

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded method that takes all the parameters: `getLeaderboardIntent (GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int timeSpan, int collection)`

You can get the intent and display the all leaderboard by:

```
Intent intent = Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(apiClient,
     leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
     LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);

// REQUEST_LEADERBOARD is an arbitrary constant to check for in onActivityResult
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

For more information see: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#displaying_a_leaderboard

Comment: Confirmed it always starts with social.  I filed a bug to have it fixed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Based on google documentation the below answer from Clayton looks perfect.
However I think there is a mismatch between google documentation and Leaderboard class.

If you try : `Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId)` it works.

If you try : `Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int timeSpan)` it works but whatever the int value you will have an Leaderboard on "All time" based.

If you try (what should be your anwser): `Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int timeSpan, int collection)` it doesn't work (the method doesn't exist).

To illustrate what I mean by "doesn't exist" you can have a look at what should be our `Leaderboard` class (lines between 49 and 51) :
https://github.com/gamea-fiks/ccc/blob/62156a697da41733afb23a63beed05e3b17a5784/sources/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.java

Another question on Stackoverflow is also about this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867659/how-to-show-public-collection-from-google-leaderboard-with-getleaderboardintent

By the way let's hope it will be corrected soon (or that I am wrong somewhere) !